# PostgreSQL select max with group by and additional value

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

With the following data `from a SELECT * FROM (SELECT...) AS foo`:

```
ID    Country   Area
1     US        100
1     UK        200
2     AU        150
2     NZ        250
```

how can you select the top area and country by `ID`? So `GROUP BY ID` and `MAX(DESC)` but also include the `County`.

The the result of the query would be:

```
1     UK     200
2     NZ     250
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID)
       ID, Country, Area
FROM   foo
ORDER  BY ID, Area DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Detailed explanation and links to faster alternatives for special cases:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select ID,Country,Area
from (SELECT...) AS foo
WHERE Area = (SELECT MAX(Area)
              FROM (SELECT...) AS foo2
              WHERE foo.ID = foo2.ID )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Erwin Brandstetters solution made it possible to do it without having to run the (SELECT.. twice).

Comment: @Matt true his answer is better!